# Can't Access Object Properties In Vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm having problems accessing object properties in Vue.
This is my component.

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <b>
            {{ posts }}
            <a :href="'https://steemit.com/&#64'+ posts.author + '/' + posts.link ">{{ posts.title }}</a>
             <a :href="'https://steemit.com/&#64'+ posts.author">{{ posts.author }}</a>
                <input @click="vote('1')"  type="button" value="Vote" >
        </b>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
            name: "vote-button",

            props: [
                'code',
                'user',
                'posts'

            ],
            methods: {
                vote: function (counter) {
                }
            }
    }

</script>
```

`{{ posts }}` prints out the whole object, which looks like this:

```
{"id":1,"title":"#1 WordPress Website","body":"![#1 WordPress Website Host ","author":"jerry","link":"1-wordpress"}
```

But if I do `{{ posts.author}}` I get undefined.

Comment: Are you sure that `posts` is an object and not a JSON string?

Comment: It might be. What should i do then?

Comment: You can parse a JSON string using `JSON.parse(value)`. In your case, you could create a computed property, say `postObj` which would just return `JSON.parse(this.posts)`. (Not sure why your `posts` prop is plural, btw, since it looks like it's supposed to just be a singular post object).

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to say for sure from what you have here, but just as an off chance guess, given that the object posts is pluralized it sounds like it might be an array. Do you get anything if you have {{ posts[0].author }} ?

Comment: This was exactly my problem. Not sure why the downvotes. I was using array.filter() to get an object from a list when I should have been using array.find() to return a single object from the array instead of a single item array of the desired object.